# sapui5 upload a file in SAPUI5 and send that file in odata service entityset

Tags: sapui5

My requirement is to
step 1 User and choose a file to upload to sapUI5
step 2 on click of "SAVE" button the file should be uploaded,
step 3 save that uploaded file in a odata entityset and send it to backend. This odata service has two entity set, both of the entity sets should go back to backend in one call.
step

I am using UploadCollection control

```
<UploadCollection      
uploadComplete="onUploadComplete"
typeMissmatch="onTypeMissmatch" 
fileSizeExceed="onFileSizeExceed" 
filenameLengthExceed="onFilenameLengthExceed" 
fileDeleted="onFileDeleted"
change="onChangeAttachments" 
noDataDescription="Drag & Drop files or use the "+" button for pending upload"                                                               
instantUpload="false"
sameFilenameAllowed="false"
multiple="true" 
maximumFileSize="10" 
maximumFilenameLength="55" 
id="UploadSet"/>
```

on save button i am calling the method

```
onStartUpload: function (oEvent) {
                var oUploadCollection = this.getView().getID

                var cFiles = oUploadCollection.getItems().length;

                        if (cFiles > 0) {
                        oUploadCollection.upload();
                        }
            },
```

My question is  on method onUploadComplete how to get the content of the file and save it in the odata entityset.

Thanks
Sonal.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this.

on click of the save button I am using a file reader to read the selected file as binary, than saving the binary in my model filecontent and than sending it to backend

```
var base64_marker = "data:" + file.type + ";base64,";
                        var reader = new FileReader();

                        reader.onload = (function (thefile) {
                            return function (evt) {
                                var base64Index = evt.target.result.indexOf(base64_marker) + base64_marker.length; // locate base64 content
                                var base64 = evt.target.result.substring(base64Index); // get base64 content
                                var oAttData = that.getModel("newInitiative").getData().rawAttachment[0];
                                var oFileData = {};
                                oFileData.ClaimType = "OFFICE";
                                oFileData.FileContent = base64;
                                oFileData.Filename = oAttData.name;
                                oFileData.Filesize = oAttData.size;
                                oFileData.Mimetype = oAttData.type;
                                that.getModel("SupplierModel").getProperty("/VendorFileSet").push(oFileData);
                            };
                        }.bind(that))(file);
```

Thanks.